# Lua table keys changes in function return

Tags: lua, opencomputers

It seems when I return a table from a function I lose they keys. Not sure if this is how Lua should be functioning.

For example

```
function main()
  local someTable = {}
  someTable["foo"] = "bar"
  print(someTable["foo"])
  return someTable
end

local test = main()
print(test["foo"])
for k, v in pairs(test) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

---

```
bar
nil
1 bar
```

Comment: This fragment works ok: https://ideone.com/K6GhrC , there must be something else involved on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok and shows the expected behaviour in a standard Lua environment like the [Lua Online Demo](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo).

```
 bar
 bar 
 foo
 bar
```

So either there is an issue with the environment you're running that script in or there is a difference between the code you posted here and the code you're running ony our machine.

Comment: This is a very delayed response. Yes it was the environment. I was able to get it to work on another computer.